# UTF-8 encoding for .sql files created or modified in SSMS

Tags: sql, encoding, sql-server-2014

The default encoding for files saved by my SSMS (v18) is ASCII, not UTF-8.
I’ve tried the steps below to set the default encoding to UTF-8 (so that I wouldn’t have to remember to set it every time I create/modify a file), but the default encoding remains ASCII.
Outside of SSMS, I can change the encoding in a text editor, but I don’t want to have to do that every time.
Have you encountered this issue and, if so, how did you resolve it?

Steps I tried:

1. From within SSMS, open the “template” file:   C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
   Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\SQLFile.sql.
2. Re-save using correct encoding:

   - File => Save As
   - Click the arrow next to the Save button
   - Choose the relevant encoding: Unicode (UTF-8 with asignature) - Codepage 65001

This is supposed to result in all new query windows having UTF-8 as the default encoding.    But, this doesn’t work for me.

Comment: Are you *sure* the encode for .sql files is ASCII? If it were, any non unicode characters would be lost; which would be a huge problem. I'm not at a PC with SSMS at the moment, but I suspect that SSMS uses UTF-16. Why, however, do you need the files to be UTF-8? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @Larnu - Good point.  What SSMS says it saves it as is "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252" which might be equivalent ot UTF-16 AFAIK.  However, the key issue is that the default is NOT UTF-8 and I want to make the default that my SSMS uses be UTF-8.  The reason I need UTF-8 is that our TFS/VSTS repo requires UTF-8.

Comment: if i remember from looking at this just a couple weeks ago, windows 1252 is a weird sort of utf8 but it's not matching 40 or 50 characters right above the ascii range like 128- 150 or 170...  wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 says it's single byte encoding.

Comment: https://joehanna.com/sql-server/changing-the-default-encoding-of-sql-files-in-ssms/ seems to have had a process that worked in 2017

Comment: @joehanna - Yep, as you can tell, I based my steps on your web page.